# get_template_part() doesn't enqueue styles if the function is included in the template part in Wordpress/PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have been struggling with diagnosing a bug on a project for hours now. I have currently narrowed it down to **what** is happening, I'm just not sure **why**:

I have a template partial called "testimonials.php" which enqueues styles at the top of the file:

```
<?php 
    add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", function() {
        wp_enqueue_style("testimonials-style", get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/partials/testimonials.css");
    });
?>
```

However, when I try to render this as a partial in a parent template, using `get_template_part('partials/testimonials')` the partial is rendered, but the CSS is not enqueued. Same for enqueueing JS files. I have verified that the pathways are correct, etc.

**If I enqueue the style in the parent Template, then the styles show up.**

Do I really need to enqueue the styles into every parent template in which I wish to include this partial?? I must be missing *something*, because this doesn't seem modular at all!

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_stylesheet' );
function my_stylesheet() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/partials/testimonials.css', false, '1.0', 'all' );
}
```

For more understanding you can see following doc
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

Comment: Please comment your code and/or offer an explanation of how this solves the posted question.

Comment: This is the way, css file needs to be en-queued from child theme.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it

Comment: Added the doc url

Comment: This doesn't solve it. I stated in my question that I have tried enqueueing the style in the template part. the problem is that partials rendered with get_template_part dont seem to bring their enqueued styles and scripts with them.

Comment: Could you please add these codes in functions.php? Let me know if it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**CSS**

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );    
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
  $parent_style = 'parent-style'; 
  wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
  wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
}
```

**JS**

```
function wpdocs_scripts_method() {
   wp_enqueue_script( 'form-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/form.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_scripts_method' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function mytheme_scripts_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'app-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/app.6e31112b.js',  array('jquery'), 1.0, true);
        wp_enqueue_style('app-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/assets/css/build.css",false,'','all');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_scripts_styles' );
```